# FFT in matlab, unexpected results

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, fft

I am playing around with FFT and cant seem to get the expected results. I have a sound clip that i recorded from a mic placed on an analogue clock. So it has a sound every second.

```
[wave,fs]=wavread('clock.wav');
t=0:1/fs:(length(wave)-1)/fs;
plot(t,wave);
n=length(wave)-1;                                             
f=0:fs/n:fs;
wavefft=abs(fft(wave));
plot(f,wavefft);
```

This is the code that i am using. And here are the results.

I should be seeing a huge spike at 1hz but i am not.

The FFT followed by the sound wave.

[image: This is the FFT]

[image: And this is the sound wave]

Comment: You should realise that in your first image, the "x" axis does not represent the actual frequency. When you perform a FFT, the result is symetric in 0Hz, and you it can be clearly seen that your FFT is symetric in 4000 or so. So the result is probably correct but you are not plotting it correctly.

Comment: @AnderBiguri It doesn't matter, becuse the spectrum is periodic around 4000, which is the fs/2 in this case. This format is the defult for `fft` function. To show the specrtum around zero, you should use `fftshift`.

Comment: @Adiel You are completely rigth, I just did a quick look to the problem and I err.

Comment: I used fft shift, and got a much nicer result. I am getting multiple peaks at equal distances from one another. Is this because the peaks are sharp, so multiples of sin/cosin are being used to make the peaks?

Comment: Also if you post that as an answer i will mark it as correct.

Comment: You can generate 1Hz sin wave with matlab code and take its fft for verification. one more thing, does analog clock sound stays for on second?

Comment: `fftshift` does not change the result, it just remove the right half to the beginning (under zero). Sharp peaks in time domain is like very fast sin/cosin period, so it cause a peak in high value (on the x-axis) in the frequency domain. "multiple peaks at equal distances" sounds a little bit strange. Anyway, `fftshift` is not an answer to your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is what your mic has recorded. Standard microphones are filtering the very low frequencies, i.e. below 20 Hz, and the sound card are probably filtering low frequencies too.

Having a tick every second does not mean that you will see a huge peak at 1Hz on your FFT. If you want to see that huge peak at 1hz, record a signal made of a sine at 1Hz. But, as I said above, be careful with low frequencies. The usual frequency for sound system testing is 1000 Hz.

Below is the time view, with zoom, of your signal clock.wav. We can see that it's composed of many harmonics, and we can **clearly** see that it is far to be a sine wave at 1Hz.

[image]

Then I filtered the signal with a low pass 2nd order type butterworth, with a cut-off frequency of 100Hz.

Please see in yellow the spectrum before the filtering, and in blue after filtering.

[image: Spectrum of the signal]
[image: Spectrum of the signal after low-pass]

So, I believe there are no big problem in your matlab code.

Comment: If you look at the picture above(the second one) you will see that the mic does pick it up.

Comment: Is still hardly believe that your input signal really has a 1Hz harmonics recorded by your soundcard. Could you please drop the file clock.wav somewhere, and I will try with my python script (using scipy.signal)? Besides that, if you want to be sure there is a 1Hz harmonics, low-pass filter your signal. Use a butterworth or Tchebychev with a 1Hz cutoff freq, and you'll see.

Comment: They are not 1hz harmonics. They are bursts of sound 1 second apart.

Comment: Ok let me really get down to the main problem. I am making an application that will be measuring heartbeat. I was doing some testing with the clock, but basically i want to know at what time does the heart beat start and when it ends.

Comment: The solution that I considered was that i would do FFT over small samples (2-4 second samples) and see where i start getting peaks around the 1hz mark. If this is not possible could you tell me what i can do?

A heart beat sounds similar and has a similar frequency to the clock and so i used that for testing.

Can you give me some advice on what sort-of techniques i should look into to solve this problem?

Comment: Ok, I understand better now. So, please close this question, and create a new one, dedicated to your main problem: How measuring heart beat starts and stops from its sound recording? Since your application is dealing with signal processing, precise if you have hardware restrictions (mobile application, desktop only, embedded..).

Comment: For your main problem, my proposal would be to use a combination of low-pass filter and envelope detection. But please ask a dedicated one.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have a lot of noise between peaks, in the time domain. It seems little in time, but is much significant in the frequency domain. Perhaps the noise main frequency is about 1000+ Hz.

Try to record again, without the clock ticks (only "silence"), and subtract it from the original signal... I doubt if it going to work, but you can try...

You can also just pick the peaks from the signal, by a simple threshold, and then you will remain just with the clock ticks.

EDIT: another suggestion is to pass the signal in low pass filter, to filter the high frequency noise.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a low frequency periodicity in the amplitude envelope of your sound clip, and not the tone waveform or pitch, you might try squaring or taking the absolute value of your signal before applying the fft, and then ignoring higher frequency bins in the result.